# Fourier transform, coefficients issue. How to gather function back?

Tags: fft

I have the output 2D array C(kx,ky) with Fourier coefficients and the problem is in how to get the function f(x,y) back using that coefficients.

f(x,y) is defined on [0,2*Pi] x [0,2*Pi] space in Fourier basis with 64 points in each direction. My output array with coefficients has the size (32,63). 32 represents only coefficients for positive wave numbers k_x > 0 and 63 is for -k_y < 0 < k_y.

In order to get the coefficients for negative k_x < 0 I do conjugate symmetry operation for C(kx,ky) i.e. np.conjugate(C) in python.

Getting back f(x,y):

```
#1st part from for k_x => 0:
for i in range(len(kx)):
    for j in range(len(ky)):
        summode = summode + c[i,j]*np.exp(1j*(kx[i]*x + ky[j]*y))

#2nd part for k_x < 0: 
for i in range(1,len(kx)):
    for j in range(len(ky)):
        summode = summode + np.conjugate(c[i,j])*np.exp(1j*(-kx[i]*x + ky[j]*y))
```

In the end, my obtained function does not match the original. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is "summode" what you wanted or possibly "summand"?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. summode is just variable, I want to get f(x,y) back using coefficients in Fourier basis.